# Can I run gitea actions witout docker?

Tags: github-actions, gitea

Im trying to start a gitea actions instance without docker. I registered the gitea act_runner and my demo is the example demo. The doc is unclear on how to do that and I wonder if its possible at all.

```
name: Gitea Actions Demo
run-name: ${{ gitea.actor }} is testing out Gitea Actions 
on: [push]

jobs:
  Explore-Gitea-Actions:
    runs-on: fedora
    steps:
      - run: echo " The job was automatically triggered by a ${{ gitea.event_name }} event."
      - run: echo " This job is now running on a ${{ runner.os }} server hosted by Gitea!"
      - run: echo " The name of your branch is ${{ gitea.ref }} and your repository is ${{ gitea.repository }}."
      #- name: Check out repository code
        #uses: actions/checkout@v3
      #- run: echo " The ${{ gitea.repository }} repository has been cloned to the runner."
      - run: echo "️ The workflow is now ready to test your code on the runner."
      - name: List files in the repository
        run: |
          ls ${{ gitea.workspace }}
      - run: echo " This job's status is ${{ job.status }}."
```

The thing is; I'm not really comfortable giving `sudo root` to `act_runner` as i would have to do `sudo act_runner exec` here to get this to work as far as I understand.

```
$  act_runner exec
INFO[0000] Using the only detected workflow event: push 
INFO[0000] Planning jobs for event: push                
INFO[0000] cache handler listens on: http://192.168.1.186:39195 
INFO[0000] Start server on http://192.168.1.186:34567   
[Gitea Actions Demo/Explore-Gitea-Actions]   Start image=node:16-bullseye
INFO[0000] Parallel tasks (0) below minimum, setting to 1 
[Gitea Actions Demo/Explore-Gitea-Actions]     docker pull image=node:16-bullseye platform= username= forcePull=false
Error: unable to determine if image already exists for image 'node:16-bullseye' (): permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/images/node:16-bullseye/json": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems a requirement: from the [Necessary prerequisites for running act](https://github.com/nektos/act#necessary-prerequisites-for-running-act):

> act depends on docker to run workflows.
>
> If you are using macOS, please be sure to follow the steps outlined in
> Docker Docs for how to install Docker Desktop for Mac.
>
> If you are using Windows, please follow steps for installing Docker
> Desktop on Windows.
>
> If you are using Linux, you will need to install Docker Engine.
>
> act is currently not supported with podman or other container backends
> (it might work, but it's not guaranteed). Please see #303 for updates.

Also the Gitea fork of act require docker to be installed. See https://gitea.com/gitea/act_runner#installation

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear in the documentaiotn but it seems that this PR remove the last thing that prevented using act_runners without Docker : https://gitea.com/gitea/act_runner/pulls/16/commits

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes. You need to configure your runners to add the label `fedora` and don't point out a docker image to it. ref https://docs.gitea.com/next/usage/actions/act-runner#labels